# An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://webtestadapter/v1 error occurring After renaming the Webtest

Tags: automated-tests, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version, webtest, nunittestadapter

I refactored the exisitng webtests(VS 2017) and they were running fine. As soon as I renamed them they are showing below error. Then I tried to rename back to the original name but still having this issue. Please help on this.

```
 ------ Discover test started ------
[ Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 1249 found (0:00:13.0770138) ==========
[Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[Warning] No test is available in C:\Code...\SupportProjectA.csproj C:\Code\...\RegressionTests.csproj C:\Code\....\Token.csproj. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

[ Error] An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://webtestadapter/v1'

Cannot find the test 'TESTA' with storage 'c:\code....\testA.webtest'
```